# Attribute Error - Where to start

Tags: django, django-models, attributes

I'm still a newbie at Django slowly figuring it out. Although I've run into this error and I don't really know where to start debugging it, since the trace back doesn't tell me the location. I think I have to look at the views.py or models.py and then figure out where the nonetype is with the filter on it but after that, I don't know.

Any insight would be appreciated.

```
Request Method: GET
Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/questions/by/test1/3/

Django Version: 1.11
Python Version: 3.5.0
Installed Applications:
['django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 'bootstrap3',
 'accounts',
 'posts',
 'groups',
 'questions',
 'django_extensions']
Installed Middleware:
['django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware']



Traceback:

File "/Users/chrismaltez/anaconda3/envs/SimpleSocialEnv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py" in inner
  41.             response = get_response(request)

File "/Users/chrismaltez/anaconda3/envs/SimpleSocialEnv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in _get_response
  187.                 response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)

File "/Users/chrismaltez/anaconda3/envs/SimpleSocialEnv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in _get_response
  185.                 response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)

File "/Users/chrismaltez/anaconda3/envs/SimpleSocialEnv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/views/generic/base.py" in view
  68.             return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)

File "/Users/chrismaltez/anaconda3/envs/SimpleSocialEnv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/views/generic/base.py" in dispatch
  88.         return handler(request, *args, **kwargs)

File "/Users/chrismaltez/anaconda3/envs/SimpleSocialEnv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/views/generic/detail.py" in get
  115.         self.object = self.get_object()

File "/Users/chrismaltez/anaconda3/envs/SimpleSocialEnv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/views/generic/detail.py" in get_object
  38.             queryset = queryset.filter(pk=pk)

Exception Type: AttributeError at /questions/by/test1/3/
Exception Value: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'filter'
```

Here is my views.py gist for questions:

```
class QuestionDetail(generic.DetailView):
    model = models.Question

    def get_queryset(self):
        queryset = super().get_queryset()


class UserQuestions(generic.ListView):
    model = models.Question
    template_name = "Questions/user_question_list.html"

    def get_queryset(self):
        try:
            self.question_user = User.objects.prefetch_related("questions").get(
                username__iexact=self.kwargs.get("username")
            )
        except User.DoesNotExist:
            raise Http404
        else:
            return self.question_user.questions.all()

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context["question_user"] = self.question_user
        return context


class CreateQuestion(generic.CreateView):
    model = models.Question
    # form = QuestionForm
    fields = ('question', 'answer')

    def form_valid(self, form):
        self.object = form.save(commit=False)
        self.object.user = self.request.user
        self.object.save()
        return super().form_valid(form)
```

Here is the models.py gist:

```
class Quiz(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=225)
    intro_text = models.TextField(null=True)
    date_created = models.DateTimeField()
    date_updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True, null=True)


class Question(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name="question", default='')
    quiz = models.ForeignKey(Quiz, related_name='quiz',default='', blank=True, null=True)
    question = models.TextField(unique=False, default='')
    question_html = models.TextField(default='')
    date_created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True, null=True)
    date_updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True, null=True)
    answer = models.TextField(default='')
    answer_html = models.TextField(unique=False, default='')
    # message = models.TextField(unique=False, default='')
    # message_html = models.TextField(editable=False, default='')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.question

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.question_html = misaka.html(self.question)
        super().save(*args, **kwargs)

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse(
            "questions:single",
            kwargs={
                "username": self.user.username,
                "pk": self.pk
            }
        )

    class Meta:
        # ordering = ["-created_at"]
        unique_together = ["user", "question", "answer", ]
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to do

```
def get_queryset(self):
    queryset = super().get_queryset()
    return queryset
```

Comment: While this may be technically correct, since the method is only returning the value from the superclass it would be much better to remove the definition completely.

Comment: I think OP is doing that because he has to do something with this overriding.

Comment: @itzMEonTV, where should this snippet go? in the views or in the models?

Comment: @DanielRoseman, thanks for the input. Which snippet of code should I remove? and why?